# Unity3D Kudan SDK Markerless Augmented Reality Help Guidance

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine, kudan

**hey all**

I am developing a furniture design augmented reality app for my dissertation and need quite a bit of help as I can't find it else where with tutorials etc.

I am doing this in Unity using the Kudan SDK AS it is pretty much the only available sdk that has SLAM technology (markerless) whereas the rest don't and others charge £2000+

I need help with implementing functions for Positioning/moving objects placed in the real world through my iPhone

I need help with implementing functions for adjusting/resizing objects through my iPhone using my fingers on the touch screen

Anyone have a tutorial/script/guidance they can help me with this?

Looking at a drop down box button that when clicked will open the drop down and each drop down item is assigned to an object. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question isn't appropriate for the site. If you had already written some code and needed help fixing it, we would be happy to help you with that. As it stands though, this is way too broad. What **exactly** do you need help with? Also requesting offsite resources like tutorials is offtopic.

Comment: I've seen 100's of stack overflow questions asking for techniques and such without code. I was looking for guidance on what's required for the input touch controls. As a whole, i need help with how to enable input touch controls pinch to size smaller or bigger, touch hold to move the object. Thats all really.

Comment: Kudan is not the only slam sdk and is not free either. Wikitude does slam for instance. Based on your comment, your pb is not even related to AR but to input.

Comment: Wikitude has a free trial with Trial plastered all over the screen... well it is related to AR?haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a plugin for Unity its called [Lean Touch](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/30111) and its Free. It has exactly what you want to achieve with 0% coding.

Comment: Awesome! Just what I needed, will it work if i created a drop down menu also??

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: The touch gestures will they work automatically if i included a drop down menu

Comment: Sorry I fail to understand. Do you mean you can set resizing on and off with a drop down?

Comment: No sorry not what i meant, once i include Lean Touch will it detect objects automatically or must each object be assigned to it

Comment: You have to say which object you would like to change the size of. But it's super simple. Also you have all documentation that you might need

Comment: Okay seems like i have all data to get cracking on, thanks so much Hristo. Will message you progress